# Why does mongoose return object Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

could somebody please tell me what is wrong with my code? Mangoose returns [[ object Object ]] and I have no idea, why.

**Model**

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    lastname: String,
    city: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', UsersSchema);
```

**Controller**

```
'use strict';

var Users = require('mongoose').model('Users');

module.exports = {

    getAll: function() {
        return Users.find({}, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(data); //   [ [ object Object ] ]
            return data;
        });
    },

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Its an `Array` of one JS `Object`. What's the question?

Comment: I expect JSON, When I try to do res.json(controllers.users.getAll()); i get TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: I'm a little rusty, but I'm fairly certain your `getAll()` method returns a promise, not the data. Try calling it with the typical promise structure.

Comment: Indeed, there's a reason `find()` has a callback, it's asynchronous, and all queries (and `save()`) in mongoose returns A+ promises.

Comment: @seva maybe you can try `controllers.user.getAll().then(data => {res.json(data)})`